# PIL Module not found even though it is installed

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, pi-2

I am able to run a program normally from the python IDLE, but unable to run the program as a sudo. (I need to work with the GPIOs, so I require to use sudo.) I get a error, that the PIL module is not found, however, it is installed using pip.

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import colorsys
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


class Process_Picture(object):
  ''' loop through each pixel and average rgb '''
  def __init__(self, imageName):

      self.pic = imageName    
      self.imgData = self.pic.load()

  def averagePixels(self):
      r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
      count = 0
      for x in range(int(self.pic.size[0])):
          for y in range(int(self.pic.size[1])):
              tempr,tempg,tempb = self.imgData[x,y]
              r += tempr
              g += tempg
              b += tempb
              count += 1
      # calculate averages
      ravg = int(r/count)
      gavg = int(g/count)
      bavg = int(b/count)
 #    print(ravg, gavg, bavg, count)
      return (ravg,gavg,bavg)

  def computeDGCI(self, rg, gg, bg):
      h,s,v =colorsys.rgb_to_hsv( rg/255, gg/255, bg/255 )
      print (h, s, v)
      HUE = 360*h
      print (HUE)
      DGCI = (((HUE-60)/60 + (1-s) + (1-v))/3)
      print (DGCI)
      return DGCI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (400, 400)
        camera.start_preview
        time.sleep ( 2 )
        camera.capture('test.jpg')
        picture1 = Image.open("test.jpg")

        #    picture1.imgData = picture1.load()                     
    pc1 = Process_Picture(picture1)
    a,b,c = pc1.averagePixels()
    print(a,b,c)
    pc1.computeDGCI(a, b, c)


        #   Divide picture in four parts

    x = int(picture1.size[0])
    y = int(picture1.size[1])
    x1 = int(picture1.size[0]/2)
    y1 = int(picture1.size[1]/2)

    picture1_1 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,0,x1,y1))
    picture1_2 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,0,x,y1))
    picture1_3 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (0,y1,x1,y))
    picture1_4 = picture1.transform(picture1.size, Image.EXTENT, (x1,y1,x,y))

        #   Compute DGCI for image segment1    
        #    picture1_1.imgData = picture1_1.load()                     
    pc1_1 = Process_Picture(picture1_1)
    R1_1,G1_1,B1_1 = pc1_1.averagePixels()
    print(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)
    DGCI_1_1 = pc1_1.computeDGCI(R1_1,G1_1,B1_1)
    #   Compute DGCI for image segment2    
        #    picture1_2.imgData = picture1_2.load()                     
    pc1_2 = Process_Picture(picture1_2)
    R1_2,G1_2,B1_2 = pc1_2.averagePixels()
    print(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)
    DGCI_1_2 = pc1_2.computeDGCI(R1_2,G1_2,B1_2)
    #   Compute DGCI for image segment3
        #   picture1_3.imgData = picture1_3.load()                     
    pc1_3 = Process_Picture(picture1_3)
    R1_3,G1_3,B1_3= pc1_3.averagePixels()
    print(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)
    DGCI_1_3 = pc1_3.computeDGCI(R1_3,G1_3,B1_3)
          #   Compute DGCI for image segment4
        #   picture1_4.imgData = picture1_4.load()                     
    pc1_4 = Process_Picture(picture1_4)
    R1_4,G1_4,B1_4 = pc1_4.averagePixels()
    print(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
    DGCI_1_4 = pc1_4.computeDGCI(R1_4,G1_4,B1_4)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    RPI.GPIO.setup(2, RPi.GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(24, 1)         
    sleep(3)              
    GPIO.output(24, 0)         
    sleep(3)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: How did you install it? Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I installed it using pip, and I am not using virtualenv.

Comment: If I remember correctly pip installs it as the user who ran the command (not root). So when you run your code as root (sudo) it can't find the library. You may be able to do sudo pip install to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried to do sudo pip-3.2 install Pillow, and it did not work.

Comment: based on how you called the program above you are using python 2.7 not 3.x so you should have done sudo pip install pillow. Also saying it didn't work does not help much what error message did you get etc.

Comment: The correct way to install a python module on a Debian/Raspbian system is from the reposotries.  Only use another method if the package is not available from the repository and you know what you are doing.  sudo apt-get install python-pil is probably what you should have done.